# Inherit specific attributes

Tags: python

Is there a way to inherit from a class only specific attributes?

For example,

```
class basic():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class inher(basic):
    def __init__(self, d, e, f):
        self.d = d
        self.e =e
        self.f = f

    def func(self):
        # here use 'a' from basic
```

I know I can inherit everything from basic:

```
class inher(basic):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        basic.__init__(self, a, b, c) #inherit these from basic
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
```

Is there a way I can inherit only argument 'a' from basic?

Comment: Seems like your `basic` class isn't atomic enough.

Comment: How would the top case work? If `inher` subclasses `basic` and `basic` requires `a`, `b` and `c` but these aren't provided to `inher`'s constructor, how else would it get them?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to initialize

Comment: ideally you should not inherit from a class if you don't need everything from that class. If a situation like this is occurring then you havn't architecture your program well. Break basic into two classes Basic and Inherit_one. Basic should only have `a` Inherit_one can have Basic inherited and b,c with itself.

Comment: If `inher` inherits from `basic`, then any instance of it also `isinstance(inh, basic)`. That means you can substitute one for the other. But if `inher` isn't a *complete* substitute, you're creating all sorts of potential problems (you're breaking the [L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))). So overall: bad idea.

Comment: You _could_ inherit everything from `basic`, and then `del` unwanted attributes, but that's still not nice, for the reasons deceze gave.  A compromise would be to override the unwanted attributes with `None` (or some other "sentinel" object). That's still not good, though.

Comment: Ok, so , I understand that although there is some kind of solution it is not recommended at all.Thank you.(I will accpet any above answer)

Comment: Just wanting/needing to do this is probably an indication that your design / abstraction / model needs improvement.